# Print a sentence in a specific place on the console in Java

Tags: java, printing

I want to print a sentence before an already printed sentence like:

```
this is your manager
//this will be printed but then I want to print a sentence

Hello there
this is your manager
```

Is it possible, if yes how can I do it?

Comment: Your request is not something that is quick and easy to do since the Java console was not built to have this capability natively, and any solution would likely be operating system dependent, requiring 3rd party libraries, or console type-dependent (e.g., using a 3rd party console). If it were me, I'd either use a GUI library or re-think my requirements.

Comment: My bad, I misread the question, it is still a good book, but I am going to remove the comment for clarity.